# Get page by full path

Tags: php, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to fetch from the Wordpress API the page contents by a slug, `pizza`, but there are a few different pizza pages. The page from which I want to fetch has the path of `/local-restaurants/pizza`.

I tried searching `/pages?slug=pizza&search=local-restaurants` but the results came back empty.

How can I specifically fetch contents from `/local-restaurants/pizza` and be sure I'm not receiving the contents of another page with the `pizza` slug?

**Edit:**
I don't know the ID number associated with the parent, just the path.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right and your full url you want to fetch from is like
`https://example.com/local-restaurants/pizza`,
than you can check for `path` in this way:

```
$url = 'https://example.com/local-restaurants/pizza';

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
//returns "/local-restaurants/pizza"
```

You can use this for conditional parsing.

Comment: I'm using the WP API with a JavaScript client, so the full URL for the WP API is `mysite.com/wp-json/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?slug=pizza`

Comment: @Himmel so you might change your url with mine from the example, won't you?